# Wrong track building with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, tracking

Faced with the situation when OpenLayers draws lines if the coordinates are "scattered".
For example:

Coords as is:
[![coords as is][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9oPP.jpg

and sorted coords by date:
[![sorted coords][2]][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkyes.jpg

The bottom image is almost correct except sharp lines show up. Sometimes the GSM signal may disappear and the coordinates are recorded in the memory of the transmitting device and as soon as a signal appears, the unsent coordinates are transmitted to the server.

How can I fix this so OpenLayers does not draw sharp lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could calculate the angles at each vertex on the linestring and remove any where the angle is sharper than your requirement.  A function such as this would do it.

```
  function checkAngles(feature, minAngle) {
    var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    var multi = (feature.getGeometry().getType() == 'MultiLineString');
    var multiCoordinates = multi ? coordinates : [coordinates];
    multiCoordinates.forEach( function(lineCoordinates) {
      var previous, previousAngle;
      var angles = [];
      lineCoordinates.forEach( function(coordinate) {
          if (previous) {
              var x = (previous[0] - coordinate[0]);
              var y = (previous[1] - coordinate[1]);
              var angle = Math.atan2(x,y);
              if (previousAngle) {
                  angles.push(((((previousAngle-angle)*180/Math.PI)+360)%360)-180);
              }
              previousAngle = angle;
          }
          previous = coordinate;
      });
      console.log(angles);
      for (i = angles.length; i > 0; i--) {
           if (Math.abs(angles[i-1]) < 10) {
               lineCoordinates.splice(i,1);
           }
      }
    });
    feature.setGeometry( multi ? new ol.geom.MultiLineString(coordinates) : new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates) );    
  }
```

Here's a demo where you can draw a linestring.  Any angles sharper than 10 degrees will be removed.  http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/linestring-angles.html

Comment: how can this be applied to multiline-string?

Comment: I've updated the function to handle both linestrings and multilinestrings (where the coordinates are arrays of linestrings).

Comment: Mike, help me pls again.
https://ibb.co/9gj3bny in blue, i marked the wrong lines. How to remove them when building a line?

Comment: Is that because the signal was lost and some of the coordinates are missing?  I think all you can do is don't include lines which don't have a minimum number of coordinates for your route.